# How to trigger textFieldDidChangeSelection only for a specific UITextField?

Tags: swift

In a view with multiple UITextField elements, textFieldDidChangeSelection will trigger for any editing done in any UITextField.
Can we perform some action inside this function only when a certain UITextField is edited?

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var text1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var text2: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var text2: UITextField!

     //..........

     func textFieldDidChangeSelection(_ textField: UITextField) {
          print(textField.text) // this code should run only for text1 for example
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to compare the textField to the one you want:

```
func textFieldDidChangeSelection(_ textField: UITextField) {
    guard textField === text1 else { return }
    print(textField.text)
}
```

Note that you should use the identity operator `===` not the equality operator `==`.

Comment: thanks, I will award Asteroid with the solution since he was the first

Comment: @cvld Asteroid's solution uses the equality operator, not the identity operator

Comment: Both solutions work but I see the point in yours. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
func textFieldDidChangeSelection(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if textField === text1 {
        print(textField.text) // this code should run only for text1 for example
    }
}
```